# How would i go about turning a method into an integer

Tags: python

Im trying to work with tkinter buttons to try and make it so when you close a button it will create another button. But I want to try and make it so no matter how many times you close the first button it wont create more than one ever.

I've tried using a compare but it says

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'
```

I want to know how to convert a method into an integer or just a better idea all togther

```
if self.printbutton < 1:
            self.printbutton()
```

I expect it to create only one button ever. Unless there are no print buttons.

Comment: You can't, you will need a variable that keeps track of how many time you called the function and compare against that. Alternatively since it's only one you could have some type of singleton pattern for your button

Comment: You should include more code. What exactly is `printbutton`?

Comment: def printbutton(self):   
        printbutton = Button(self.frame, text="Print Events " + str(self.buttoncounter()), command = self.buttoncounter, width=15)
        printbutton.pack( side = LEFT )

This is the print button

Answer (score 0):

omg!
 in tkinter, the button actions are in config

```
command =<method>
```

let  be pop_only_once(...),
if it was like

```
button.config( command = partial(pop_only_once,...,button))
```

so to make it only ones is to write inside the method:

```
def pop_only_once(..., button)

...

button.config( command =None)
```